# C++ Semantics of calling reset on a unique pointer in a destructor

Tags: c++, destructor, heap-memory, unique-ptr

Say we have a simple struct with a unique pointer in a hpp file:

```
struct SomeType
{
    SomeType() = default;
    ~SomeType();
    
    std::unique_ptr<int> ptr;
};
```

In the cpp we then have:

```
SomeType::~SomeType()
{
    ptr.reset();
}
```

Is this destructor somehow useful or just superfluous?
Is there any chance of a double delete or other unwanted side-effects on memory/heap?

Comment: Superfluous with a unique ptr

Comment: There might be some cases where you need to free `ptr` before you run some code in your destructor or before you free some other member, but in general it it superfluous.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If that's the only line of code in the destructor it is unnecessary, it will happen either way. All members destructors are called after the parent destructor automatically.

It may be useful if you have some other stuff to do in the destructor and/or the exact order of actions is important.

Double deletion will not happen.